# Clean up this list to only keep the most recent crawl based on the year

Tags: python

I have a list which looks like this:

```
[<GET https://web.archive.org/web/20110518083020id_/http://www.rollsroyce.com/about/index.jsp>, <GET https://web.archive.org/web/20110617060411id_/http://www.rollsroyce.com/about/index.jsp>, <GET https://web.archive.org/web/20110810011112id_/http://www.rollsroyce.com/about/index.jsp>, <GET https://web.archive.org/web/20120120013630id_/http://rollsroyce.com/about/index.jsp>, <GET https://web.archive.org/web/20120124115631id_/http://rollsroyce.com/about/index.jsp>, <GET https://web.archive.org/web/20120127145524id_/http://rollsroyce.com/about/index.jsp>, <GET https://web.archive.org/web/20120131060020id_/http://rollsroyce.com/about/index.jsp>, <GET https://web.archive.org/web/20120210041718id_/http://rollsroyce.com/about/index.jsp>, <GET https://web.archive.org/web/20120214181911id_/http://rollsroyce.com/about/index.jsp>, <GET https://web.archive.org/web/20120224215742id_/http://rollsroyce.com/about/index.jsp>, <GET https://web.archive.org/web/20120318055019id_/http://rollsroyce.com/about/index.jsp>,]
```

I want to deduplicate this list based on the URL which succeeds "id_/" and only keep the most recent version per year of the URL based on the timestamp.

The two URLs I would like to keep are:

```
[<GET https://web.archive.org/web/20110810011112id_/http://www.rollsroyce.com/about/index.jsp>, https://web.archive.org/web/20120318055019id_/http://rollsroyce.com/about/index.jsp>]
```

What's the quickest way to do this? These are not always in order.

I guess the logic would be something like:
Loop through the list, split on "id_", store the URL, store the datetime stamp, convert to a datetime obj, store all of these in an inner list based on the year, sort the list and keep the most recent one, store the index of the most recent one in an outer list?

Comment: What happened if you did it in the way you have described?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'm just not sure I've implemented it correctly, posted my way of doing it below.

Comment: If someone gave you a solution here, how would you know if it is correct?

Comment: I'd run it through a few examples and check what I expect the result to be.

Comment: Now you can do the same with your own solution to find out if it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer but I'm not sure if it's correct:

```py
# deduplicate the array, keep only one entry per URL per year
items_to_keep = []
year_dict = {}
for i in my_array:
    url = i.split('id_/')[1]
    datetime_str = i.split('web/')[1].split('id_/')[0]
    datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    year = datetime_obj.year
    if url not in year_dict:
        year_dict[url] = year
        items_to_keep.append(i)
    elif year_dict[url] != year:
        year_dict[url] = year
        items_to_keep.append(i)

print(items_to_keep)
```

Comment: Did you test this? Do you have any reason to believe it isn't correct?

Comment: Since you only want the most recent one for every URL, and you say your list is not guaranteed to be sorted, why not try your code with an example list containing unsorted entries for a _single_ URL. Does it work as expected? If not, why do you think it doesn't? (One reason I can see right off the bat is, if you want to keep only the most recent timestamp, what does your code do to enforce this condition?)